# Why df.interpotale() doesn't work in my python3? why does it return the exact same dataframe withut any interpolation?

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

my code for `df.interpolate` was:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd
from IPython.display import display
from scipy import interpolate

pd.set_option('display.max_rows',54100)

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\tanvir random practice\gazipur.xlsx', parse_date=["DateTime"], index_col='DateTime']

df.interpolate(method="linear").bfill()
display(df)
```

Comment: You need to provide sample data and expected results

Comment: You are not saving it by `df = df.interpolate(method="linear")` - once you do that, then try to display